# Get list of variable from string of specific format

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a complex string which can have variable in specific format as `/##{[^}{\(\)\[\]\-\+\*\/]+?}##/g` I want to extract those variables in an array.

e.g.

```
var x= "sgsegsg##{xx}gerweg##{xx1}##rgewrgwgwrg}##ferwfwer##{xx2}rgrg##{xx3}####{xx4}####{errg}}}";

function getVariableNames (param) {
   return param.match(/(##{[^}{\(\)\[\]\-\+\*\/]+?}##)+?/g)
}

getVariableNames(x);
```

above lines returns `["##{xx1}##", "##{xx3}##", "##{xx4}##"]`

where I want to get `['xx1', 'xx3', 'xx4']`

Comment: Why not `xx` and `xx2` in the result?

Comment: as they don't have format `##{[^}{\(\)\[\]\-\+\*\/ ]+?}##` which start and ends on two '#' and enclosed inside curly braces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your pattern, because the portion inside the `##`s won't contain curly braces, simply repeating non-curly braces is enough: `[^}]+`. Match the repeated non-bracket characters, and then iterate through the matches and extract the captured group:

```js
const str = "sgsegsg##{xx}gerweg##{xx1}##rgewrgwgwrg}##ferwfwer##{xx2}rgrg##{xx3}####{xx4}####{errg}}}";
const pattern = /##{([^}]+)}##/g;
let match;
const matches = [];
while (match = pattern.exec(str)) {
  matches.push(match[1]);
}
console.log(matches);
```

On newer environments, you can lookbehind for `##{` instead:

```js
const str = "sgsegsg##{xx}gerweg##{xx1}##rgewrgwgwrg}##ferwfwer##{xx2}rgrg##{xx3}####{xx4}####{errg}}}";
const pattern = /(?<=##{)[^}]+(?=}##)/g;
console.log(str.match(pattern));
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with following and it worked:

```
var x= "sgsegsg##{xx}gerweg##{xx1}##rgewrgwgwrg}##ferwfwer##{xx2}rgrg##{xx3}####{xx4}####{errg}##{xx5(}####{xx-6}####{xx7}##}}";

function getVariableNames (str) {
    let variables = str.match(/(##{[^}{)(\]\[\-+*\/]+?}##)+?/g);
    return variables && variables.length  ? variables.map(i=>i.substring(3, i.length - 3)) : false;
}

getVariableNames(x)
```